# Python not importing files as modules correctly

Tags: python, xampp, cgi

I am trying to get Python code to work on a web browser using the CGI module, as well as some other file modules that I am trying to import into the main program.

My initial program, which works as required, is the following:

```
#!C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

import cgi

def htmlTop():
    print("Content-type: text/html")
    print()
    print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                    <title>My Server Side Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>""")

def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
    </html>""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        htmlTop()
        print("Hello World")
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

In the same folder as this program, I have a Python file called "_serverTestModules" containing:

```
def _serverTestFunction():
print("The file has been imported successfully")
```

If I then add:

```
import _serverTestModules
```

to the original file, both of which are in the same directory, and attempt to access the function from the original code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xampp/htdocs/inventorysystem/_serverTest.py", line 26, in <module>
    _serverTestFunction()
NameError: name '_serverTestFunction' is not defined
```

So basically my test program works, but as soon as I try to import functions from other files which are in the same directory (something which I need for my main project), the code fails. Is this a problem with the computer system or the network? Every other answer I have seen on Stack Overflow has either had no answer or an incorrect answer, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this

```
from _serverTestModules import _serverTestFunction
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however my other files have many functions inside of them, is there a way to import all of the functions from a file into the main program at once? I have tried using from _serverTestModules import * however this does not work.

Comment: you can use from _serverTestModules import *

Comment: I tried doing that in the main file and it did not work. Any other suggestions?